# How to know if document exists in firestore python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

im using the firestore library from google.cloud, 
is there any way to check if a document exists without retrieven all the data?
i tried

```
fs.document("path/to/document").get().exists()
```

but it returns a 404 error. (google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound)

then i tried

```
fs.document("path/to/document").exists()
```

but "exists" isn't a function from DocumentReference.

I can see from the source that exists() is a function from the DocumentSnapshot Class, and the function get() should return a documentSnapshot. i'm not very sure how else i can get a DocumentSnapshot

Thank you

Comment: I have this same problem, on firebase admin v 2.14.0, where `db.collection('...').document('...').get()` throws `google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404` when the doc doesn't exist.  It's very strange, this seems to be a recent problem on my server and works fine on my macbook install (where `....get().exists` returns False with no exception)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A much simpler and memory efficient approach:

```
doc_ref = db.collection('my_collection').document('my_document')
doc = doc_ref.get()
if doc.exists:
    logging.info("Found")
else:
    logging.info("Not found")
```

Note: this lazy loads the document by not fetching the content. So this is faster then getting the whole document. This does count as a single read.

[Source](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-firestore/firestore-python-check-if-document-exist/)

Comment: Does this count as a "read" and thus in the costs?

Comment: It does count as a read, but not the whole document is fetched. So in terms of latency it is the fastest approach.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `firebase-admin`:

```
fs.collection('items').document('item-id').get().exists
```

`True` iff `items/item-id` exists.

Alternatively

```
'item-id' in (d.id for d in fs.collection('items').get())
```

Comment: This will not work properly with very large collections, because you have to pull everything in memory!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
docRef      = db.collection('collectionName').document('documentID')
docSnapshot = docRef.get([]); # Empty array for fields to get
isExists    = docSnapshot.exists
```

With this approach, you will retrieve an empty document. You will incur cost of 'reading', but there will be reduced network egress and almost zero change in in-use memory of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the document in order to know if it exists or not.  If the document exists, it will count as a read.

Comment: Oh, an official answer from a Firebase insider... Thanks for the concise answer, but wouldn't it be a useful feature to know if a document exists without knowing its contents?  :o